# How to configure JNDI Environment variable in weblogic and access it via java code

Tags: java, weblogic, jndi

The web application I am working on stores some configuration data in JNDI environment variable. The application is being designed and intended to work across J2EE application servers.  I things working in Tomcat , JBoss but not in weblogic 12c. Not finding any link in the Weblogic’s admin console to configure the Environment entries.

Let me explain the how it works in tomcat.

`<Environment name="APP_DIRPATH" value="c:\webtemp\" type="java.lang.String"/>
<Environment name="APP_LOG " value="true" type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
<Environment name="APP_FILE_THRESHOLD" value="10000" type="java.lang.Integer"/>`

These can be configured in JBoss too through its admin console
Following java code enables to pickup the above entries :

`InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();
String PFX = "java:/comp/env/";
NamingEnumeration<NameClassPair> namingEnumeration = initContext.list(PFX);`

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: WebLogic uses the standard way to configure init parameter for your web application. Read this [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1025195) to create env entries in your application

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically we do not want to store environment variable web.xml... the purpose is to deploy the war in compressed state.....does not weblogic have an UI in its admin console

Comment: it is not possible to update these variables with an UI or with the admin console. But, it is possible to handle this use case when you do not want to update the application and you need to externalize configuration values : use a deployment plan as described in this [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/09-DeployPlan--4464/deployplan.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your help is highly appreciated.